# Given data matrix and error matrix, find value of $x,y,z$

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

In an exercise about multiple regression, I'm given the following data matrix $X$ and error vector $\epsilon$:

$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 4 & x \\
    1 & -2 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 4 \\
    1 & -2 & 8 \\
    1 & y & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}~, \quad \epsilon = \begin{bmatrix}
    z \\
    4 \\
    5 \\
    -7 \\
    -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm asked to find $x,y$ and $z$ but I don't know what to do. I thought the formula of $Y = \beta X + \epsilon$ might help but it doesn't do much since we don't know $\beta$ nor $Y$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer:
Through properties of the residuals we know that $X^{T}\epsilon = 0$ so all we need to do is solve the following system:
\begin{align}
z + 4 + 5 -7 - 1 = 0\\
4z - 8 + 5 + 14 - y = 0\\
xz + 4 + 20 - 56 -2 = 0
\end{align}
So that
\begin{align}
z = -1 \\
y = 7 \\
x = -34
\end{align}